# A sentence that I don't understand

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-meaning

How do you read this sentence:

> "Mischel remembers graduate students’ desks giving way to mattresses, and large packages from Ciba chemicals, in Switzerland, arriving in the mail."

The first part is clear: students have a mess on their desks. But after the comma it becomes weird, Ciba is a company based in Switzerland so I guess the author wrote a minimal description of what Ciba chemicals are.

Is it ok to write about the desks and then about the contents of the mail like that? How would you rewrite that sentence so that it is easier to read?

Comment: It says nothing about the desks being messy; it implies that they were cleared away to make room for mattresses, as though the classroom were being made into a dormitory. Do you have a context for the sentence which would explain the connection with packages of chemicals arriving?

Comment: https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2009/05/18/dont-2
While Mischel was beginning to dismantle the methods of his field, the Harvard psychology department was in tumult. In 1960, the personality psychologist Timothy Leary helped start the Harvard Psilocybin Project, which consisted mostly of self-experimentation. Mischel remembers graduate students’ desks giving way to mattresses, and large packages from Ciba chemicals, in Switzerland, arriving in the mail. Mischel had nothing against hippies, but he wanted modern psychology to be rigorous and empirical.

Comment: I would not rewrite the sentence so that it is easier to read. It's a wonderful sentence that I would leave untouched.

Answer (score 2):

With the OP's explanation that this relates to the Harvard Psilocybin Project:

It appears that the graduate students were testing psychedelic drugs on themselves, so their desks had been moved away to make room for mattresses to lie on, and supplies of the drugs arrived regularly from the manufacturers, Ciba.

The two occurrences are mentioned in the same sentence because they are significant things that Mischel remembers about that period.